# Insert the scrollbar value into input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scrollbar

I've this script, inspired by the codrops slider pagination concept http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/21/slider-pagination-concept/
I'd like to put the value obtained by the slider into an input field value (i.e.  ) instead of into the div#preview.
How can I do ?
Thanks

KD

```
<div class="container"> 
            <div id="preview" type="text" class="preview">0</div>

            <div id="slider" class="sp-slider-wrapper">
            </div>

    </div><!-- /container -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.pagination.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var $update = $( '#preview' );
            $( "#slider" ).pagination( {
                total : 12,
                onChange : function( value ) {
                    $update.text( value );
                }
            } );
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `val()`

```
 $('#yourInputID').val(value);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"> 
        <div id="preview" type="text" class="preview">0</div>
        <div id="slider" class="sp-slider-wrapper"></div>
        <input id="test" value=""/> <--- input here
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
        var $update = $( '#preview' );
        $( "#slider" ).pagination( {
            total : 12,
            onChange : function( value ) {
                $('#test').val(value);
            }
        } );
    });
```